# 'Cannot find name' compile error for imported required module

Tags: javascript, socket.io, typescript

i have the code like this:

```
///<reference path='typescript_defs/node.d.ts' />
///<reference path='typescript_defs/socket.io.d.ts' />
import sio = require('socket.io');

function main(io: sio.Server) {
    io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket: sio.Socket) {
    }); 
}
main(sio.listen(4444));
```

i expected that this would work after reading and looking at other examples, but it gives a name error at sio.Server and sio.Socket

> support.ts(12,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'sio'.
>
> support.ts(14,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'sio'.

if i put 'string' in replace of 'sio.Socket' to intentionally get an error it tells me the expected type is Server. now, whether i use sio.Server or Server, it makes no difference there is still a name error and i don't understand how i'm supposed to make use of the types in .d.ts files and cant find documentation or examples that work for it.

hope someone can help me! thanks~

Comment: I see that it's not the case here, but these errors also show up when you don't put your type references at the very top of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the [.d.ts file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/socket.io/socket.io.d.ts), the expected type name is actually `SocketIO.Server` (not `sio.Server`). This particular .d.ts file exposes the type names globally instead of through an external module export.

The odd error here (cannot find name 'sio') is because there's nothing in the *type* namespace called `sio`.

Comment: thank you! i see understand that it works now thank yuu! and sorry for not including that .d.ts file but yes thats the same one i used  i forget! i'm happy now :)